# Query wordpress posts on static page

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm working with Wordpress theme  where i need to show  my  posts  in a static page.There is a  only one section in site where  we need to add posts frequently (services) and i need to fetch these posts on services page .

I did not know how to workout with  loop in a static page , if someone could help with it that would be great help

Comment: you might want to ask here instead: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

If all the posts are tagged with "services" then the archive page http://example.com/category/services/ will display all those posts.